# how to make ZxingScanner start scanning?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, zxing, zxing.net, zxing.net.mobile

I am trying to implement barcode scanning in my Xamarin form, but no success.
I am able to get the camera working, but I don't see the red line on the screen and it simply refuses to scan anything

I tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67934028/zxing-zxingscannerpage-torch-flashlight-not-working-xamarin-forms). I can see thru my camera, but no red line appears. But I can put the torch on and off

**XAML code:**

```
<Button  BackgroundColor="Chocolate" Clicked="Button_Clicked"/>
<zxing:ZXingScannerView 
    x:Name="_scanView" 
    OnScanResult="Handle_OnScanResult" 
    IsScanning="true" 
    IsAnalyzing="true"
    WidthRequest="200" 
    HeightRequest="200" />
```

**C# Code:**

```
private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _scanView.ToggleTorch();
}

private void Handle_OnScanResult(ZXing.Result result)
{
    ChassisEntry.Text = result.Text;
}


// this is in the constructor of the page
MobileBarcodeScanningOptions options = new ZXing.Mobile.MobileBarcodeScanningOptions()
{
    TryHarder = true,
    PossibleFormats = new List<ZXing.BarcodeFormat>() { ZXing.BarcodeFormat.All_1D }
};
_scanView.Options = options;
```

What am I missing ?

**EDIT**

I have this in my `MainActivity.cs`

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
    global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
    ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms.Android.Platform.Init();
    LoadApplication(new App());
}

public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
{
   Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
   ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms.Android.PermissionsHandler.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

   base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
}
```

**Addition to the answer**

@Rafeal 's answer is working for me, the only problem is that there is no red line on the scan view.
I found this `workaround` for that problem.
However, it is a workaround because I notice that the scan already happens if the barcode is anywhere in the view.
Though this might not appear a problem, in my case I have paper forms with up to 20 barcodes on it, and when the user wants to aim at a particular barcode he might get the wrong one.

So if anybody knows a better solution I would like to hear it.
I will make a separate question on SO about this problem.

This is the workaround I am using now

```
  <Grid VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                <zxing:ZXingScannerView
                    x:Name="_scanView"
                    OnScanResult="Handle_OnScanResult"
                    IsScanning="true"
                    WidthRequest="200"
                    HeightRequest="200"/>


                <zxing:ZXingDefaultOverlay
                    x:Name="scannerOverlay"                                                       
                    BottomText="Place the red line over the barcode you'd like to scan.">

                </zxing:ZXingDefaultOverlay>
            </Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my working project I used this xaml declaration:

```xml
<zxing:ZXingScannerView x:Name="qrCodeScannerView" 
                        OnScanResult="Handle_OnScanResult" 
                        IsScanning="true"
                        WidthRequest="1024" 
                        HeightRequest="400" />
```

Note, that I did not set `isAnalyzing` property in the xaml declaration as you did. As the page appears, the zxing control starts working and analyzing immediately.

Then in `xaml.cs` file

```cs
        public void Handle_OnScanResult(Result scanResult)
        {
                qrCodeScannerView.IsScanning = false;
                // processing scanResult.Text here
        }

        protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();
            qrCodeScannerView.IsScanning = true;
        }

        protected override void OnDisappearing()
        {
            base.OnDisappearing();
            qrCodeScannerView.IsScanning = false;
        }
```

That looks strange, but setting `isScanning` property also in xaml.cs file solved this task for me.

Comment: While this scans, I do not see the red line to move over the barcode. How can I do that ?

Comment: I do not see the red line too while it scans. I just align the camera against the qr-code. And it catches it and analyzes immediately.

Comment: OK But I really need to see that red line, my customer will not be satisfied without it. Any ideas ?

Comment: I am sorry, but I have no idea how to add a red line over the zxing control. In my project I've added a label above the control with the text: `Point the camera at the QR code. Once the QR code is recognized, you will be automatically redirected to the next step.`. And my customer was happy with it.

Comment: I am not scanning QR codes, but 1D codes. Sometimes there is a page with many barcodes on it, without the red line (like every scanner I know has) it will be difficult to point to the correct barcode

Comment: I have accepted your answer, because it fixed the problem in my question. I would however still like a solution for the red line problem.

Comment: @GuidoG I think it would be good to ask a separate question about the red line on zxing control.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the ZXingScannerView from your XAML completely. On a clicked event of a button add this code:

```
private async void ButtonScan(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PermissionStatus granted = await Permissions.CheckStatusAsync<Permissions.Camera>();
    if (granted != PermissionStatus.Granted)
    {
        _ = await Permissions.RequestAsync<Permissions.Camera>();
    }
    if (granted == PermissionStatus.Granted)
    {
        try
        {
            MobileBarcodeScanner scanner = new MobileBarcodeScanner();
            ZXing.Result result = await scanner.Scan();
            if (result != null && result.Text != "")
            {
                //You access your scanned text with result.Text
                scanner.Cancel(); // <--- This closes the scanner
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Problem", "Something went wrong.", "ΟΚ");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        await DisplayAlert("Problem", "No permissions to use camera.", "ΟΚ");
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

OP mentioned i should add this line of code to my answer in order to make it work.

In the MainActivity.cs you have to initialize the scanner like this:

```
ZXing.Mobile.MobileBarcodeScanner.Initialize(Application);
```

Comment: Let me know if you need an example for continuous scanning as well.

Comment: I get `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` on this line `ZXing.Result result = await scanner.Scan();`

Comment: So the scanner is null? On my MainActivity.cs i initialize like this `ZXing.Mobile.MobileBarcodeScanner.Initialize(Application);`. Can you try it? My example is for the red line you need.

Comment: I will try it, but you should put this very relevant information in your answer !

Comment: With this extra line in the MainActivity this also works, but you should put that extra line of code in your answer !

Comment: Do you have any idea how I could add some buttons to this scan screen ?

Comment: I don't believe it's possible to add buttons with this way of scanning, but don't take my word for it. I haven't gone this deep with scanning. I also added the line you suggested to my answer. Thanks.